# Flask error when request file from server

Tags: python, http, flask, post, frameworks

Hi i am getting error in upload function i have another file index html file where user uploads the file and

```
`#Error#: RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.[Finished in 0.6s]`
```

This error is occuring on line in my uploader function:
code:

```
`
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
   return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      file1_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD'], secure_filename(FileIO.filename))
      f1 = request.files['file1']
      f1.save(file1_path)
      file2_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD'], secure_filename(FileIO.filename))
      f2 = request.files['file2']
      f2.save(file2_path)
      return file1_path, file2_path 
`

`
file1_path=uploader()
file2_path=uploader()
with open(file1_path, 'r') as file1:
   data = file1.read().replace('\n', '')
   str1=data.replace(' ', '')
with open(file2_path, 'r') as file2:
   data = file2.read().replace('\n', '')
   str2=data.replace(' ', '')
if(len(str1)>len(str2)):
   length=len(str1)
else:
   length=len(str2)
print(100-round((levenshtein(str1,str2)/length)*100,2),'% Similarity')
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `uploader` function has the decotrator `@route`. when this decorator applies to a function that function will expect an active `request` object when its being called meaning if you call that function it should be a http/https request. since you are calling it from your .py file and it doesn't create any request while calling the function therefore it will fail.

you can manually test your code without any active request. for more help refer to this flask documentation for more info on request context and how you can achieve what you want.
[FLASK DOCS REQUEST](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/)